# Layout issues problematic with drag and drop

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have 3 containers. A big one where I have all my ImageView and 2 other ones where the user needs to categorize.

[image]

I use LinearLayout.

Questions: the 3rd image view (beans) is shown reduced. How can I have regular imageview with space between them and if there are no space left, I'd like to to the next row.

Then I drag & dop the almond, apple, banana image views to the 2 container and get the followig result.

[image]

I would like the banana to appear in the 2nd row.

I have the same questions than above:

-how to have regular size imageviews

-how can I get spaces between (cosmetic)

-how to show the 3rd image on the 2nd row of my container

Are they recommendations on the way to have a nice look and feel?

I include below my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topleft"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/almond" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/apple" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/banana" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/beans" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomleft"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topright"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomright"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, after thinking about it and some testing, that I need to manage it manually: position, width/height, ....
Let me know if I have other options.

Comment: Yes, using properly Views, such GridView, where the Data is represented by the Adapter and not a lot of if/elses such yours.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get what I want with controlling programatically the position of the imageview(s) in RelativeLayout(s). it's cumbersome but works well.